# Magento Add extra fee in checkout

Tags: magento, checkout

I want to add a checkbox in the checkout for customer to click if they want an extra service and if they click, an extra fixed fee must be added to the subtotal.

How can I add the fixed fee when the customer select the checkbox?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: I want to use your second option how can I activate the adding extra fee event on click? @Santosh Patel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing that:

1. Add the service as a **cross-sell product** in the checkout from Magento backend. You don't need any programming knowledge for that.
2. Build a small **custom module** for adding an extra fee in the checkout process. In this case you need php and Magento backend development knowledge. See this Github reference: https://github.com/magentix/Fee

Comment: How can I add the click event to the custom module? So that it reloads the checkout page with the fee? @Alain Banutz

Answer (score 0):

Add custom option with product as checkbox. Then you will use this custom option during checkout.